# Ralink rt3290 - how to reach declared 802.11n speed on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, ralink, ubuntu-drivers

Maximum bit rate for RT3290 driver shown by **sudo iwlist scan** is 54.

But **lshw -C network** tell me that my wireless card support 300 megabit 802.11n - "RT3290 Wireless 802.11n 1T/1R PCIe".

Windows / Android / iOS devices working fast as it is usual for 802.11n.

How to do the same for Ubuntu 14.04 netbook with RT3290?

Comment: What does _iwconfig_ report?

Comment: @chili555

    lo        no wireless extensions.
    
    eth1      no wireless extensions.
    
    wlan1     IEEE 802.11bgn  ESSID:"Bulash.Home"  
              Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.422 GHz  Access Point: 00:8E:F2:58:93:64   
              Bit Rate=65 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
              Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
              Power Management:off
              Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
              Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
              Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:41   Missed beacon:0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see here, your wireless device is clearly in N-speeds:

```
Bit Rate=65 Mb/s
```

The rate shown in scanning is always 54 Mb/s if the router is capable of at least G speeds and even if the router is capable of N and AC speeds. As you can see from your own *iwconfig,* the wireless device and the router will negotiate the best speed in the connection process.

I know of no method to force the hardware, driver and router to cease negotiations and force 300 Mb/s speeds. There are some things you can try in the router. WPA2-AES is preferred; not any WPA and WPA2 mixed mode and certainly not TKIP. Second, I have better luck with a channel width of 20 MHz in the 2.4 GHz band instead of automatic 20/40 MHz. I also have better luck with a fixed channel, either 1, 6 or 11, rather than automatic channel selection. After making these changes, reboot the router.

Next, I recommend that your regulatory domain be set explicitly. Check yours:

```
sudo iw reg get
```

If you get 00, that is a one-size-maybe-fits-all setting. Find yours here: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2 Then set it temporarily:

```
sudo iw reg set IS
```

Of course, substitute your country code if not Iceland. Set it permanently:

```
gksudo gedit /etc/default/crda
```

Use nano or kate or leafpad if you don't have the text editor gedit.

Change the last line to read:

```
REGDOMAIN=IS
```

Proofread carefully, save and close the text editor.

Next, I'd set IPv6 to Ignore in Network Manager: http://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/Fedora/18/html/Installation_Guide/images/netconfig/network-connections-ipv6-ignore.png  This example is for ethernet, but you want wireless.

Comment: How can  it help to set  regulatory domain  explicitly?