# Intel Dual Band Wireless 7260 can not connect

Tags: 14.04, wireless, thinkpad, intel-wireless

Fresh Ubuntu 14.04.1 install (kernel 3.13.0-44), fully updated (via wired connection) and with correct iwlwifi firmware driver (iwlwifi-7260-8).

Lenovo ThinkPad S440.

I can connect to the wireless network, here at work, from both Mac OS X, Windows 7 and from Ubuntu 14.04 on another ThinkPad (T500). I restarted the router to no avail.

I'm pretty clueless to what I should do to troubleshoot this issue and are grateful for any help.

#### About my system:

`lspci|grep -i wi`: `04:00.0 Network controller: Intel Corporation Wireless 7260 (rev 83)`

`sudo iwconfig`:

```
eth0      no wireless extensions.

lo        no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abgn  ESSID:off/any  
          Mode:Managed  Access Point: Not-Associated   Tx-Power=22 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Encryption key:off
          Power Management:on
```

`nm-tool`:

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: disconnected

- Device: wlan0 ----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            iwlwifi
  State:             disconnected
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        F8:16:54:27:B5:A5

  Capabilities:

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points 
    FULLRATEAEBA:    Infra, C0:3F:0E:B0:AE:BA, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA WPA2
    Catalin_103:     Infra, C0:A0:BB:8D:18:19, Freq 2422 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 34 WPA WPA2


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            r8169
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        F8:A9:63:55:91:79

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off


`rfkill list`:
0: tpacpi_bluetooth_sw: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
2: phy0: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

`dmesg|grep iwl`:

```
[    6.465125] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: irq 63 for MSI/MSI-X
[    6.476126] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: loaded firmware version 22.24.8.0 op_mode iwlmvm
[    6.524174] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    6.524437] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.524673] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.739827] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.940780] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.941012] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[  223.540907] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Time Event end notification failure
```

`sudo lshw`:

```
*-pci:2
             description: PCI bridge
             product: Lynx Point-LP PCI Express Root Port 3
             vendor: Intel Corporation
             physical id: 1c.2
             bus info: pci@0000:00:1c.2
             version: e4
             width: 32 bits
             clock: 33MHz
             capabilities: pci pciexpress msi pm normal_decode bus_master cap_list
             configuration: driver=pcieport
             resources: irq:18 memory:f0600000-f06fffff
           *-network
                description: Wireless interface
                product: Wireless 7260
                vendor: Intel Corporation
                physical id: 0
                bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
                logical name: wlan0
                version: 83
                serial: f8:16:54:27:b5:a5
                width: 64 bits
                clock: 33MHz
                capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
                configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlwifi driverversion=3.13.0-44-generic firmware=22.24.8.0 latency=0 link=no multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abgn
                resources: irq:63 memory:f0600000-f0601fff
```

### Update

I'm trying to connect to `FULLRATEAEBA: Infra, C0:3F:0E:B0:AE:BA, Freq 2412 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 59 WPA WPA2`
When I look in the message buffer I it looks like I'm connected and authenticated but then for unexplainable reasons, the kernel deauthenticate.

```
[ 2748.066675] wlan0: authenticate with c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba
[ 2748.068670] wlan0: send auth to c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (try 1/3)
[ 2748.070496] wlan0: authenticated
[ 2748.073360] wlan0: associate with c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (try 1/3)
[ 2748.077787] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=5)
[ 2748.079346] wlan0: associated
[ 2793.931365] wlan0: deauthenticating from c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba by local choice (reason=3)
```

### update 2

I found that I can connect at home without issues but I still can not connect at work. The weird thing is that I have an old T500 with ubuntu 14.04 that connects fine at work.
Below is the `dmesg` messages.

**dmesg for a connection fail (at work)**:

```
[ 5554.192997] wlan0: authenticate with c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba
[ 5554.195347] wlan0: send auth to c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (try 1/3)
[ 5554.200817] wlan0: authenticated
[ 5554.201603] wlan0: associate with c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (try 1/3)
[ 5554.205520] wlan0: RX AssocResp from c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=8)
[ 5554.206777] wlan0: associated
[ 5600.638632] wlan0: deauthenticating from c0:3f:0e:b0:ae:ba by local choice (reason=3)
[ 5600.642070] cfg80211: Calling CRDA to update world regulatory domain
[ 5600.645259] cfg80211: World regulatory domain updated:
[ 5600.645262] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5600.645264] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.645266] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.645268] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.645269] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.645270] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.645279] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DK
[ 5600.647737] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DK
[ 5600.647741] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[ 5600.647743] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.647744] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.647745] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[ 5600.647747] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
[ 5600.647748] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
```

**dmesg for a connection success (at home)**:

```
[    6.532911] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: Detected Intel(R) Dual Band Wireless AC 7260, REV=0x144
[    6.532993] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.533233] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.664207] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[    6.664209] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2472000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.664211] cfg80211:   (2457000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.664212] cfg80211:   (2474000 KHz - 2494000 KHz @ 20000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.664214] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.664215] cfg80211:   (5735000 KHz - 5835000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (300 mBi, 2000 mBm)
[    6.711736] init: failsafe main process (660) killed by TERM signal
[    6.740856] ieee80211 phy0: Selected rate control algorithm 'iwl-mvm-rs'
[    6.761147] intel_rapl: domain uncore energy ctr 7461:7461 not working, skip
[    6.873429] r8169 0000:03:00.0 eth0: link down
[    6.873991] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.874237] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): eth0: link is not ready
[    6.875681] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.875917] iwlwifi 0000:04:00.0: L1 Enabled - LTR Enabled
[    6.884761] type=1400 audit(1421181675.200:11): apparmor="STATUS" operation="profile_load" profile="unconfined" name="/usr/lib/lightdm/lightdm-guest-session" pid=956 comm="apparmor_parser"
[    6.891403] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    6.891964] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_UP): wlan0: link is not ready
[    7.553843] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[    7.559276] init: plymouth-upstart-bridge main process ended, respawning
[   10.489646] wlan0: authenticate with 52:67:f0:d5:cd:fc
[   10.491707] wlan0: send auth to 52:67:f0:d5:cd:fc (try 1/3)
[   10.498811] wlan0: authenticated
[   10.501626] wlan0: associate with 52:67:f0:d5:cd:fc (try 1/3)
[   10.511184] wlan0: RX AssocResp from 52:67:f0:d5:cd:fc (capab=0x411 status=0 aid=3)
[   10.511997] wlan0: associated
[   10.512017] IPv6: ADDRCONF(NETDEV_CHANGE): wlan0: link becomes ready
[   10.512062] cfg80211: Calling CRDA for country: DK
[   10.513768] cfg80211: Regulatory domain changed to country: DK
[   10.513769] cfg80211:   (start_freq - end_freq @ bandwidth), (max_antenna_gain, max_eirp)
[   10.513771] cfg80211:   (2402000 KHz - 2482000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   10.513772] cfg80211:   (5170000 KHz - 5250000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   10.513772] cfg80211:   (5250000 KHz - 5330000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2000 mBm)
[   10.513773] cfg80211:   (5490000 KHz - 5710000 KHz @ 40000 KHz), (N/A, 2700 mBm)
[   10.513774] cfg80211:   (57240000 KHz - 65880000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 4000 mBm)
[   11.115993] IPv6: wlan0: IPv6 duplicate address fe80::fa16:54ff:fe27:b5a5 detected!
```

I did a system check with `checkbox` to test the wireless hardware and got a fail in wireless/wireless_connection. But the error message is a bit bewildering.
`Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag`

Comment: Before I propose any other solution, I suggest you start with the steps I recommended here: http://askubuntu.com/questions/496249/ralink-rt3290-how-to-reach-declared-802-11n-speed-on-ubuntu-14-04/496515#496515

Comment: I set the regulatory domain to DK and tried to connect - to no avail. I then used the network manager to ignore IPv6 - also to no avail. `dmesg` has the same info as I posted in the *update*.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you download and install the -9 firmware. Perhaps the driver will accept and load the -9 firmware in preference to the -8 that is now loading: 'loaded firmware version 22.24.**8**.0 op_mode iwlmvm.' Go here and download http://wireless.kernel.org/en/users/Drivers/iwlwifi?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=iwlwifi-7260-ucode-25.228.9.0.tgz Drag and drop it to your desktop. Right-click it and select 'Extract Here.' Now, in a terminal:

```
cd ~/Desktop/iwlwifi-7260-ucode-22.228.9.0
cp iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode  /lib/firmware
```

Reboot and check:

```
dmesg | grep iwl
```

We might also try a driver parameter:

```
sudo -i
echo "options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/iwlwifi.conf
exit
```

Reboot and tell us if the issue remains.

Comment: Thanks for using your time to help me @chili555. I already have iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode installed. `ls | grep -i iwlwifi-7260`: iwlwifi-7260-7.ucode, iwlwifi-7260-8.ucode, iwlwifi-7260-9.ucode I tried to disable -8.ucode as you said but after a reboot nothing has changed.

Comment: Hmm.. According to `dmesg` the 22.24.8.0 is still being loaded even after writing `options iwlwifi 11n_disable=8` to the end of *iwlwifi.conf*

Comment: The 8s,in this case, are coincidental and unrelated. Is the connection improved at all?

Comment: yes and no. I meant to update the question with my latest findings. It's a bit time consuming because I can't connect with my S440, here at work. But, I found that I can connect at home without issues. The weird thing is that I have an old T500 with the same ubuntu version that connects fine at work. I will update the question with the `dmesg`from my latest connection try and try to find the messages, from where I successfully connect at home. But it'll have to wait 'till I finish work today.